# ForLoop Iterations as List Index in Django Template

Tags: python, django, loops

I'm building a django webpage but I seem to have hit a snag as I can't really figure out how to use the current iteration of a for loop (in the template) for multiple lists:

```
        {% for num in loopRange %}
    <tr>
        {% for num2 in subRange %}
        <td>{% cycle list1 list2 list3 list4 %}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

I found a couple questions here stackoverflow that were similar and I attempted to use cycle, but alas this just resulted in all members of the list being printed each time--not exactly unexpected but I can't figure out how for the life of me.

What I have is multiple lists that are all similar in content, each list is a column in a row.  So, if it was python and I was concatenating strings it would be like this:

```
for i in xrange(5):
    string = list1[i] + list2[i] + list3[i] + list 4[i]
```

So basically that.  I'm passing each list in as context in addition to two xranges (loopRange and Subrange in the first example), I need five rows (each list has five members) and four columns (four lists).

EDIT: I suppose in a nuthshell I want to refer to list indeces as foo[bar], done in django as foo.bar, however bar apparently can't be an integer an iterable range passed in as content

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that the best approach would be to work on the data in the view before passing it to the template.

For example, the `zip` builtin can be used to create the rows list based on the lists that contain the columns:

```
rows = zip(list1, list2, list3, list4)
```

After that, the template can iterate over the rows one by one and access the columns using index access if needed:

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {{row.0}} {{row.1}} {{row.2}} {{row.3}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That solves it!  Fantastic.  zip() is a very handy function for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a simple filter to return an item from the list:

```
@register.filter
def get_item(row, i):
    try:
        return row[i]
    except IndexError:
        return ''
```

Then:

```
{{ list1|get_item:num2 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would really like to do this in your templates themselves for some reason, you can also write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#setting-a-variable-in-the-context) that does it for you:

```
#app/templatetags/zip.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

class Zipper(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, format_string, var_name):
        self.format_string = format_string
        self.var_name = var_name
    def render(self, context):
        zippables = [context[tok] for tok in self.format_string.split()]
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        context[self.var_name] = zip(*zippables)
        return ''

import re

@register.tag(name="zip")
def do_zip(parser, token):
    try:
        # Splitting by None == splitting by spaces.
        tag_name, arg = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag requires arguments" % token.contents.split()[0])
    m = re.search(r'(.*?) as (\w+)', arg)
    if not m:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag had invalid arguments" % tag_name)
    format_string, var_name = m.groups()
    return Zipper(format_string, var_name)
```

**Note**: this syntax is about to get a lot simpler in Django 1.4, due to the addition of `assignment_tag`.

Then, just use it like this:

```
{%load zip%}

{% zip list1 list2 list3 list4 as list_of_rows %}
```

You can then use `list_of_rows` wherever you want in that block, including inside two nested for loops.